# What other word/phrase that can be used in alternate with "I just realized"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Example,

> I just realized why some people still choose him even in the middle of
>   the latter's allegations of corruption. It is because...

Alternative phrases for *I just realized*

Answer (score 2):

You can use

> - Now I got to know that ...
> - I discovered ....
> - I just figured out ...
> - Now I know ...
> - I found out ...

Formal

> - I cognized ...
> - I had an epiphany ...

Comment: These are mostly good, but "Now I got to know that" doesn't sound right to me. I can't put my finger on a specific error, but it definitely isn't idiomatic. And using "cognize" as you propose seems to be technically correct but will come across as extremely pompous - I don't think I've ever seen this usage, even in formal academic writing.

Comment: Yes, it was sounds fishy to me as well "Now I got to know that ...", that is why I included "Now I know ...". I think there is no need to specify "Now" with a past form of "get".

Comment: I'd steer away from _cognized_.

Answer (score 2):

Two more:

> "It came to my attention"
>
> "I came to the conclusion"

although these would probably work better with "...that" instead of "...why":

> I came to the conclusion that some people still choose him even in the middle of the allegations of corruption, because...

Answer (score 1):

For a use of the passive construction,

**It just occurred to me**

**It just hit me**

**It just dawned on me**.